# Compare 2 tree in python treelib

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, compare, graph-algorithm

any way to efficiently compare 2 trees in treelib?

return true if 2 tree is identical

by identical, the matched node should have the same tag, and the parent son relationships between every matched node in the two tree are the same

Answer (score 0):

```
from treelib import Node, Tree

def compare_trees(node1, node2): 
  # reimplement this comparison based on your needs: use data,...
  if(node1.tag != node2.tag):
    return False
  else:
    # access global trees
    children1 = tree1.children(node1.identifier)
    children2 = tree2.children(node2.identifier)

    if len(children1) != len(children2):
      return False
    elif len(children1) > 0:
      # recusivly compare children
      return all([compare_trees(c1i, c2i) for c1i, c2i in zip(children1, children2)])
    else:
      return True

tree1 = Tree()
tree1.create_node("Harry", "harry")  # root node
tree1.create_node("Jane", "jane", parent="harry")
tree1.create_node("Bill", "bill", parent="harry")

tree2 = Tree()
tree2.create_node("Harry", "harry")  # root node
tree2.create_node("Jane", "jane", parent="harry")
tree2.create_node("Bill", "bill", parent="harry")

compare_trees(tree1.get_node(tree1.root), tree2.get_node(tree2.root))
```